# Starcraft 2 WoL achievements in HotS

Tags: achievements, starcraft-2

I am just wondering if any of the achievements earned in WoL will be completely carried over to HotS. I've heard that in HotS achievements seem to be based on a new system, called levelling system. Would that change the state of any existing WoL achievements?

Let's say, in WoL I need to win 10 more team games as Terran to unlock rewards for 1K team Terran wins, will I also need to win 10 games as Terran in HotS?

Comment: They will probably be moved into a sub category, or made into Feats of Strength. As far as I heard there is nothing official though

Comment: i play the beta and after win 10 games with zerg you win the clasic drone portrait, besides of your hots level, however today is the release of pre hots patch

Answer (score 3):

All the achievements from Wings of Liberty will be carried over, nothing lost.

- Campaign achievements will obviously stay. There will be a new category for Heart of the Swarm campaign.
- Ladder and vs AI achievements will stay, though some are renamed (e.g. hardest AI level is now "Elite" instead of "Insane").

The new reward system will function alongside old one. There will still be portraits ot earn for "reach X wins with Y race" achievements, and new portraits and decals will be awarded for "swarm levels".